# Onchange event in dynamic table html

Tags: javascript, dynamic, datatable, onchange, onblur

My requirement is I have a table having 4 columns 
in first cloumn can select item name, second is item rate, third is item qty last one is the total amount
I want to get the item rate automaticaly in second column while changing item in first, and want tom get the total after focus out from qty field as the multiple opf qty and rate,
i want a row adding buton to add rows and the onchange and onblur event should working on all rows,
how can i do this ?
my coode is

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<table id="item_table">
<tr><th>SL No</th><th>Item Name</th><th>Rate</th><th>Qty</th><th>Total</th><th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add" >add</button></tr>
</table>




 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
      var html = '';
      html += '<tr>';
       html += '<td><input type="text" name="slno[]" /></td>';
       html += '<td><select name="item[]" id=item[] onchange="show_rate()"><option value="10">Item 1</option><option value="20">Item 2</option><option value="30">Item 3</option><option value="35">Item 4</option></td>';
      html += '<td><input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate[]" /></td>';
      html += '<td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty[]" onblur="sum_total()"/></td>';
      html += '<td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total[]" /></td>';
     html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove" >Remove</button></td></tr>';
      $('#item_table').append(html);
     });

     $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     });
});
function show_rate(){
    var a=document.getElementsByName("item[]")[0].value;
    var b=document.getElementById("rate[]");
    b.value=a;
}
function capitalise(){
    var c=document.getElementsByName("rate[]")[0].value;
    var d=document.getElementsByName("qty[]")[0].value;
    var e=document.getElementById("total[]");
    e.value=+c * +d;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Code updated plese check

Answer (score 0):

You must make your select with values in the option tags. Each option must have a unique ID or name. You can then call upon the value attribute of the option and display it in column 2. Then use simple math operators to take the value and multiply it by a set variable, which you can also get from a select by using the mentioned above method. Example 12

Look at other posts for questions about adding rows, there are tons of posts out there on that topic with exactly the code you need.

Comment: Also, if you use Jquery it can make the selection of attributes significantly easier. Look at http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: I did it for single row it works,but by adding rows dynamicaly , event is not not working